# SQL обновить данные в таблице

Tags: sql, postgresql, функции

Имеется 3 таблицы `tab1`, `tab2`, `tab3`. В таблице `tab2` внешним ключом `id_tab1` является `id` таблицы `tab1`; в таблице `tab3` внешний ключ `id_tab2` - `id` таблицы `tab2`.
Нужно сделать хранимую функцию с входными параметрами `id_tab1`, `id_tab2` и `value`, которая будет обновлять данные, лежащие в таблице `tab3` значением `value`. Если такой записи в таблице `tab3` нет, то нужно ее создать.
Подскажите как это реализовать.

Comment: Это mysql? Почему нужна именно хранимая процедура?

Comment: нужно прочитать мануалы, их много и на русском есть. а про хранимку - это верное решение , надо только почитать.

Comment: поставьте тег соответствющего сервера. MS SQL, Oracle, MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция принимает 3 парметра id_tab1, id_tab2 и value

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION insval(integer,integer,character) RETURNS integer AS

DECLARE i integer;

BEGIN
    if exists( select 1 from tab3 where id_tab2=$2) then
    begin 
        update tab3 set value = $3 where id_tab2=$2;
        i:=0;

    end; 
    else
    begin
        insert into tab3(...)  values (...$3);  
        i:=1; 
    end;
    endif;
END; 

'LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

i для определения действия если надо